# PySpark flip key/value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to flip key value from a dataset to do sorting. However, the map function return an invalid syntax error

```py
rdd = clean_headers_rdd.rdd\
        .filter(lambda x: x['date'].year == 2016)\
        .map(lambda x: (x['user_id'], 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)\
        .map(lambda (x, y): (y, x)).sortByKey(ascending = False)
```

[image]

Comment: try `lambda x: (x[1],x[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PEP 3113 -- Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/).

- Method recommended by [the transition plan](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/#transition-plan):

  ```py
  rdd.map(lambda x_y: (x_y[1],  x_y[0])
  ```
- Shortcut with the `operator` module:

  ```py
  from operator import itemgetter

  rdd.map(itemgetter(1, 0))
  ```
- Slicing:

  ```py
  rdd.map(lambda x: x[::-1])
  ```