# zip unpacking with lampda in spark python 3.5

Tags: apache-spark, lambda, zip, python-3.5, rdd

the problem this code work fine with python 2.x n the new python 3.5 in Apache spark how to find work around this issue perform tuple concatenation.
the code.

```
 from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics
    import random
    column1 = sc.parallelize(range(100))
    column2 = sc.parallelize(range(100,200))
    column3 = sc.parallelize(list(reversed(range(100))))
    column4 = sc.parallelize(random.sample(range(100),100))
    data = column1.zip(column2).zip(column3).zip(column4).map(lambda (((a,b),c),d) : (a,b,c,d) ).map(lambda (a,b,c,d) : [a,b,c,d])
    print(Statistics.corr(data))
```

the error

```
 File "<ipython-input-19-e505a170fcab>", line 7
    data = column1.zip(column2).zip(column3).zip(column4).map(lambda (((a,b),c),d) : (a,b,c,d) ).map(lambda (a,b,c,d) : [a,b,c,d])
                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

usually when there is only two part this work

```
rdd.map(lambda x_y: (x_y[1],  x_y[0])
```

but with tuple like this (((a,b),c),d) how to do it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PySpark flip key/value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804345/pyspark-flip-key-value)

Comment: i tried using  the indexing but how to write index something like this (((a,b),c),d) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace:

```
.map(lambda (((a,b),c),d) : (a,b,c,d) ) \ 
.map(lambda (a,b,c,d) : [a,b,c,d])
```

with

```
.map(lambda x (((a,b),c),d) : [x[0][0][0],x[0][0][1], x[0][1], x[1]])
```